# Communicating between two WordPress site using REST API & without any authentication

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have 2 WordPress sites in 2 different domains. One is my server & another one is my client site. In my server WordPress, I have a custom WordPress REST API endpoint that accepts POST requests. The client will send some custom data to the server. Then the server processes the data & returns an output.

The issue is that I can't use any authentication method here. The API must be public & any WordPress site can send some data to the server. In the server's REST API callback function, I have added some custom sanitization & validation. Also, nothing to be saved in the DATABASE.

I have added the below code snippet to make a public API endpoint in my server.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_route_abcd' );
function register_rest_route_abcd() {
register_rest_route(
    'mycustomapi', 'v1/abcd',
    array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => array( 'my_callback_function'),
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    )
);
}
```

Then in the client file, I have used `wp_safe_remote_post` to post my custom data.

```
wp_safe_remote_post( $target_url, array('body' => $request_data) )
```

The requested data is custom data & there are no authentication parameters there. I got the error given below.

```
{"code":"rest_not_logged_in","message":"You are not currently logged in.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I need a public API endpoint where anyone can submit some data.

NOTE: I have a custom string like a key in the submitted data & can I use that string to authenticate API response?

---

**Update: The issue was automatically resolved. I haven't done any changes in the code or file.**

I have attached the code snippet that will be useful for someone else. Public API that accepts POST requests is always vulnerable. So be careful. I believe that later we can get some suggestions regarding it.

**In server-side**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_route_abcd');

function register_rest_route_abcd() {
    register_rest_route(
        'myapi', 'v1/myroute',
        array(
            'methods' => 'POST,GET',
            'callback' => 'my_callback_function',
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        )
    );
}

function my_callback_function($request){
    
    //Do logic here
    
    // Prepare response
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'done';
    
    return $response;
}
```

**In clint side**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ed45r_my_action', 5 );
function ed45r_my_action(){
    
        $target_url = 'http://localhost/server-sys/wp-json/myapi/v1/myroute';
    
        $data = array(
            'key_1' => 'value_1',
            'key_2' => 'value_2',
        );
        
        $request = wp_safe_remote_get( $target_url, array('body' => $data) );
        
        if(is_wp_error($request) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($request) != 200){
            
            // Know the errror
            
        } else {
            
            $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
            $response = json_decode($response, true);
            
            // Process the response
            
        }
    
}
```

In my case, the action is not a `template_redirect`. It is a form submission.

Comment: I just ran your first block of code with the endpoint `/wp-json/mycustomapi/v1/abcd` and submitted a POST to it, and it came back with a success. Are you sure there's nothing i the callback that might be sending back an error?

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas . Also, when I do a wp_safe_remote_post on a template redirect, there is no error. But when I submit a form data, the error happens. I think the nonce in the form makes this error. I'm trying again to replicate the issues.

Comment: The issue is not related to nonce. The issue was automatically resolved! Anyway, I will share the code I have used to make the communication. May it will be helpful for some others.